# Wix installer hide application in use warning after upgrade

Tags: wix, outlook-addin, clickonce, addin-express

I develop an Outlook plug-in in C# using Addin express. The installer is based on Wix using ClickTwice:) for deployment and upgrades. We have a seamless upgrade process from our plug-in where new versions are downloaded automatically.

However, because Outlook is open when the installation process is launched, we receive a pop-up once download is complete notifying the user to close Outlook. See screenshot available from link:

[Application in use warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDpJO.png)

Our users are very non-technical, and they will most likely close this message by clicking cancel or the X button, which cancels the installation. We are already able to show our own message to the user explaining what to do, but we would really like to hide the automated message so that our users don't get confused.

Is there any way to disable this message or to automatically select an option for the user without the pop-up appearing? Our installer configuration file is Product.wxs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The dialog doesn't come from WIX. Instead, you may take a look at the *Preferences* of your *ClickTwice* solution. By default, you may see the following picture:

[image]

So, there you may configure to not display any dialogs.